# Error in yii insert statement SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, yii

While inserting data into a table in Yii, I am getting this error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement:
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined.
The SQL statement executed was: insert into user_feedback (name,
desc,email,mobilenumber) values (:Name, :Desc,:email,:Mobilenmber).
```

below is my code :

```
$sql = "insert into user_feedback (name, desc,email,mobilenumber) values (:Name, :Desc,:email,:Mobilenmber)";
      $parameters = array(":name"=>$_POST['Name'], ':desc' => $_POST['Desc'],':email'=>$_POST['email'],':mobile_number'=>$_POST['Mobile_nmber']);
      Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute($parameters);
```

Comment: Please take more care with the formatting of your posts. If your question is hard to read you won't get any answers. I fixed it for you.

Comment: The parameter names and their representations in the SQL statement dont match. (`:Name` vs. `:name`, `:Mobilenmber` vs `:mobile_number`, ...) Make em match.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 mistakes on your request. As Alexander said, your parameters didn't match (all expect email). And there is typo mistake.

This request/param should work :

```
$sql = "insert into user_feedback (name, desc,email,mobilenumber) values (:name, :desc,:email,:mobile_number)";
      $parameters = array(":name"=>$_POST['Name'], ':desc' => $_POST['Desc'],':email'=>$_POST['email'],':mobile_number'=>$_POST['Mobile_number']);
```

Comment: I am new to yii ,that's why i did this mistake .i want to make it more clear ,in insert statement values field should have request parameters names or sql table columns name ?

Comment: @user3381968 Nop, we are here to help ;) I hope it solve your problem.

Comment: ,No after these changes and executing my code now i am getting another error :(

Comment: @user3381968 I miss your previous question: When you use `:` you are calling paramaters. So your parameters (the text in your array) and the text after `:` have to be the same.

Comment: Error is still the same ?

Comment: No Now i am getting below error :                                                                                      Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc,email,mobile_number) values ('hello', 'test','test','999999999')' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: insert into user_feedback (name, desc,email,mobile_number) values (:name, :desc,:email,:mobile_number);

Comment: Any suggestions please ,i am not getting how to fix above error .

Comment: What is the structure of your table ? Only String ? Or the last value is a number ? If it's a number, you shouldn't have this quote. Also, can you show us the request once the valu are set and before the excution. It could help to notice syntax error.

Comment: :) ,fixed it ,there was error in mysql table column name ,it was treating desc   as sql command ,after changing column name to description ,finally data getting inserted into table .thanks to all for finding out mistakes in my code :)

Answer (score 1):

Fix the parameter name to match the ones in select statement, try executing this using queryAll as follows :

```
$sql = "insert into user_feedback (name, desc,email,mobilenumber) values (:Name, :Desc,:Email,:Mobilenmber)"; 

$parameters = array(
    ":Name"=>$_POST['Name'],  // names match paremeters in select
    ':Desc' => $_POST['Desc'], // names match paremeters in select
    ':Email'=>$_POST['email'], // names match paremeters in select
    ':Mobilenmber'=>$_POST['Mobile_number']); // names match paremeters 
    // in select plus there is a problem 
    //  with with key (typo) Mobile_number and not Mobile_nmber (unless you defined it this way on purpose !!!)

$command  = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
$result = $command->queryAll(true,$parameters);
```

**Edit**

I bet the issue is really with the `name` column, it is a MYSQL keyword [name](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3863/), please change the column name to something else and try it out

Comment: my cod is working fine only when i am inserting data in one column once i modify it to two columns ,it started throwing below error :             Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc) values ('Testing','Ignore')' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: insert into employee (name,desc) values (:name,:desc)

Comment: can you log the executed query? or try to print the built query from within the db class??